# Deeply embedded divs with complex structure

Tags: css

I am trying to structure my divs as depicted on the picture below:

[image]

and having trouble finding the respective css syntax that is best suited to achieve this. I know about `display:flex` and `overflow-y:auto`, but this technique does not work for me for multiple levels of embedded divs.

I am a newbie in css, and the odds are that such question is already asked, but I can't think of the right key words to research it.

https://jsfiddle.net/5p4mrmm6/

Comment: display:grid would do , here float could also if sizes are static ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would probably be the general structure, though it's up to you to figure out the widths and dimensions. I gave a class of `.grow` to make an element take up all of the available space - reuse that as you see fit.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.col {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.parent {
  max-width: 960px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

.a {
  background: pink;
}
.b {
  background: orange;
}
.c {
  background: red;
}
.d {
  background: brown;
}
.e {
  background: yellow;
}
.f {
  background: turquoise;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex parent">
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="flex col grow">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="b">b</div>
      <div class="flex col grow">
        <div class="flex">
          <div class="c">c</div>
          <div class="grow d">d</div>
        </div>
        <div class="e">e</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grow f">
      f
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With float; you can do somehing similar but with fixed size:

```css
div {
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  filter: blur(0.5px);/* to look like your image */
}

.a {
  background: #F4CCCC;
  height: 110px;
  width: 73px;
}

.b {
  background: #FF9900;
  width: 55px;
  height: 44px;
}

.c {
  background: #FF0000;
  width: 60px;
  height: 21px;
}

.d {
  background: #BF9000;
  height: 21px;
  width: 102px;
}

.e {
  background: #FFFF00;
  width: 162px;
  height: 23px
}

.f {
  background: #00FFFF;
  width: 217px;
  height: 66px
}

body {
  width: 290px;
  margin: 2em;
  ;
}
```

```html
<div class=a> A</div>
<div class=b> B</div>
<div class=c> C</div>
<div class=d> D</div>
<div class=e> E</div>
<div class=f> F</div>
```

If you have enabled your browsers to use the grid system, then you could use this in the future :

```css
body {
  height:100vh;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 20% 15% auto;
  grid-template-rows: 25%  25% auto;
}
div {
   display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  filter: blur(0.5px);
}

.a {
  background: #F4CCCC;
  grid-row:1 / 4;
}

.b {
  background: #FF9900;
    grid-row:1 / 3;
}

.c {
  background: #FF0000;
}

.d {
  background: #BF9000;
}

.e {
  background: #FFFF00;
    grid-column:3 / 5;
}

.f {
  background: #00FFFF;
    grid-column:2 / 5;
}
```

```html
<div class=a> A</div>
<div class=b> B</div>
<div class=c> C</div>
<div class=d> D</div>
<div class=e> E</div>
<div class=f> F</div>
```