# CSS - horizontal alignment with embedded divs

Tags: css

Following on [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42029828/deeply-embedded-divs-with-complex-structure/42030011#42030011), my goal now is to make the `time` element with value `2017-01-01 21:10` appear right-aligned near the left border of the element with blue border.

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y9rbhh03/):

Comment: Why are you appending all of your classes in your CSS with the element they belong to?

Comment: Do you mean why am I writing `div.dialog_list {...}` instead of `.dialog_list {..}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To strictly achieve your goal, you need to add this `CSS` to yours:

```
.message_info {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.message_preview_heading {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Typically, you should write `CSS` (or any other type of code, really) trying to use the minimum required amount of code to achieve your goal. Additionally, in CSS, you want to use the weakest selectors, to be able to maintain and adjust code with ease at later times.

Currently, most of your selectors are over-qualified (too specific). You don't need classes over all levels of an element. Usually a specific class at the top level of a certain module is enough to be able to style it.

---

With the hope it will help you better understand the general principles outlined above, I recreated your layout following best practices (like I would for a client). Here is the code I would write for this layout: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/97cs3uub/ (note it's in `SCSS`, which allows for shorter syntax and nesting).

And this would be the end result to be deployed on production, after parsing and prefixing (skipped minification for readability):

```css
.dialog_list {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 490px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
          box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12); }
  .dialog_list > .photo {
    width: 45px;
    height: 55px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin-right: 10px; }
    .dialog_list > .photo > img {
      -o-object-fit: contain;
         object-fit: contain; }
  .dialog_list > .message {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
       -moz-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex-positive: 1;
            flex-grow: 1; }
    .dialog_list > .message > .header {
      font-size: .9rem;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -moz-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
         -moz-box-pack: justify;
          -ms-flex-pack: justify;
              justify-content: space-between;
      margin-bottom: 10px; }
    .dialog_list > .message > .body {
      font-family: serif;
      font-style: italic; }

body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5; }
```

```html
<div class="dialog_list">
  <div class="photo">
   <!-- place the <img> here -->
  </div>
  <div class="message">
    <div class="header">
      <span class="number">+7 916 1770000</span>
      <span class="time">2017-01-01 21:10</span>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
    Hello, Sam. Are you ok?   
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```